# How to get the probability of a text belonging to a topic in GSDMM?

Tags: nlp, topic-modeling

In LDA, there is a way to extract the probability of a text belonging to a topic. Is there something similar in GSM? If so, what is the package and code?

thanks

Comment: Do you mean GSDMM or GSM? It seems that either title or the body of your question contains a typo.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this implementation of GSDMM](https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm), you can get this probability using the [`score` method of `MovieGroupProcess` class](https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm/blob/f170c0f6272f09e9ce5acf0309d4fbedc08c0579/gsdmm/mgp.py#L157):

```
    def score(self, doc):
    '''
    Score a document
    Implements formula (3) of Yin and Wang 2014.
    http://dbgroup.cs.tsinghua.edu.cn/wangjy/papers/KDD14-GSDMM.pdf
    :param doc: list[str]: The doc token stream
    :return: list[float]: A length K probability vector where each component represents
                          the probability of the document appearing in a particular cluster
    '''
```

It can be used as follows:

```
>> mgp.score(["my", "beautiful", "text", "is", "here"])
[(0, 5.408052732645677e-10),
(1, 2.2084257143830565e-05),
(2, 0.022683564559983955),
(3, 0.0009818820143112778),
(4, 0.5482598416951635),          
(5, 0.1022196373411148),
(6, 0.049452600413189024),
(7, 1.710484812050781e-06),
(8, 0.004729435817210187),
(9, 8.314540183290251e-06),
(10, 0.13690067779136778),
(11, 0.00018238304274319198),
(12, 5.3021228234619835e-05),
(13, 0.010612516369262397),
(14, 7.432649699440398e-05),
(15, 0.004651235422841561),
(16, 0.001587346363887785),
(17, 0.005119983861692937),
(18, 6.710854911425749e-05),
(19, 0.11239232920994387)]
```

It returns the pairs `(topic id, probability)`.

Please note that the `score` function accepts the list of tokens, not the string itself. If you pass

```
mgp.score("my beautiful text is here")
```

it will be treated as

```
mgp.score(['m', 'y', ' ', 'b', 'e', 'a', 'u', 't', 'i', 'f', 'u', 'l', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'])
```